# Understanding how many parallel workers remain from a worker pool across sessions for PostgreSQL parallel queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-12, postgresql-parallel-query

Let's say I have a pool of 4 parallel workers in my PostgreSQL database configuration. I also have 2 sessions.

In session#1, the SQL is currently executing, with my planner randomly choosing to launch 2 workers for this query.

So, in session#2, how can I know that my pool of workers has decreased by 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can count the parallel worker backends:

```
SELECT current_setting('max_parallel_workers')::integer AS max_workers,
       count(*) AS active_workers
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE backend_type = 'parallel worker';
```

Comment: Let's say that an SQL query reserves 2 parallel workers. Will the max_parallel_worker variable decrease by 2 until the SQL query is finished executing? The parameter that does this - if it even exists at all - is what I am looking for.

Comment: There is no parameter for that. I didn't read up in the source; perhaps there is a global variable that you could access from a C function, but certainly not from SQL. What's wrong with a query?

Comment: simply subtract the two numbers my query returns, and you have your result.

Comment: I had tested this on a Postgres 10.7 **Aurora** instance. Interestingly, it reported "background worker" instead of "parallel worker" for parallel workers. (Verified parallelism with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.) Testing the same in a pure Postgres instance, it reported  "parallel worker" as expected. May be due to Aurora implementing parallelism differently behind the scenes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for looking. Well, using closed source PostgreSQL forks has certain disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Postgres keeps track of how many parallel workers are active with two variables named `parallel_register_count` and `parallel_terminate_count`. The difference between the two is the number of active parallel workers. [See comment in in the source code.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/backend/postmaster/bgworker.c#L85)

Before registering a new parallel worker, this number is checked against the `max_parallel_workers` setting [in the source code here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/backend/postmaster/bgworker.c#L937).

Unfortunately, I don't know of any direct way to expose this information to the user.

You'll see the effects of an exhausted limit in query plans. You might try `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with a `SELECT` query on a big table that's normally parallelized. You would see fewer workers used than workers planned. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/how-parallel-query-works.html)

> The total number of background workers that can exist at any one time
>   is limited by both [max_worker_processes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-WORKER-PROCESSES) and [max_parallel_workers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS).
>   Therefore, it is possible for a parallel query to run with fewer
>   workers than planned, or even with no workers at all.

Comment: Thanks; this is quite similar to what I am looking for. Just for clarification, if I issue a query reserving 2 workers, then when I do `parallel_terminate_count` - `parallel_register_count`, I shall see 2? I suppose that is what it says but I do not really understand the purpose of `parallel_terminate_count`.

Comment: @baceda9220: Reversed: `parallel_register_count - parallel_terminate_count` - it's the number of registered (used) parallel workers minus the number of terminated. But those are internal variables in the C code. I don't know of a way to expose them to the user. Laurenz has a more practical approach.